SymFromAddr() causes Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
I am currently trying to write a simple profiler based on this tutorial. It uses SymFromAddr() of the dbghlp.h library to resolve function addresses to their names. The function addresses are passed as a DWORD64 to Findfunction() from another function that takes it from the _penter and _pexit assembler code.
I got it working with a small example program. However, when trying to use it in a bigger project with boost test it fails with this error:

Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBDBA6B699 (KernelBase.dll) in MyTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

The same exception is thrown if I want to print the output of GetCurrentProcess() in the large project. But the same thing works in the smaller project.
I first thought it had to do with SymFromAddr() not being thread-safe. Therefore, I put it in a thread-safe Singleton so that there is at most one call to it at a time. Unfortunately, this changed nothing.
This is my code so far:
#include "pch.h"
#include "SymbolResolverSingleton.h"
#include <imagehlp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <strsafe.h>

//Base address of the loaded module
static DWORD64  dwBaseAddr = 0;

//Flag to indicate the result of symbol initialization
static BOOL     bInitResult = FALSE;


SymbolResolverSingleton::SymbolResolverSingleton(const void* pAddress)
{
    InitSymbols(pAddress);
}

SymbolResolverSingleton::~SymbolResolverSingleton() = default;

void SymbolResolverSingleton::InitSymbols(const void* pAddress)
{
    //Query the memory
    char moduleName[MAX_PATH];
    //TCHAR modShortNameBuf[MAX_PATH];
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;

    //Get the module name where the address is available
    VirtualQuery((void*)pAddress, &mbi, sizeof(mbi));
    GetModuleFileNameA((HMODULE)mbi.AllocationBase,
        moduleName, MAX_PATH);

    //Initialize the symbols
    bInitResult = SymInitialize(GetCurrentProcess(), moduleName, TRUE);


    //Load the module
    dwBaseAddr = SymLoadModule64(GetCurrentProcess(),
        NULL,
        (PCSTR)moduleName,
        NULL,
        (DWORD)mbi.AllocationBase,
        0);
    //Set the options
    SymSetOptions(SymGetOptions() & ~SYMOPT_UNDNAME);
}

void SymbolResolverSingleton::FindFunction(DWORD64 pa, char*& szFuncName)
{
    DWORD64 symDisplacement;

    if (dwBaseAddr)
    {
        //Allocate the memory for PSYMBOL_INFO
        TCHAR  buffer[sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO) + MAX_SYM_NAME * sizeof(TCHAR)];
        memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
        PSYMBOL_INFO    pSymbolInfo = (PSYMBOL_INFO)buffer;
        pSymbolInfo->SizeOfStruct = sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO);
        pSymbolInfo->MaxNameLen = MAX_SYM_NAME;

        //Get the name of the symbol using the address
        BOOL bResult = SymFromAddr(GetCurrentProcess(), pa, &symDisplacement, pSymbolInfo);

        LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
        LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;

        //If symbol is found, then get its undecorated name.The name could be a decorated one
        //as the name mangling schemes are deployed
        if (bResult)
        {
            char undName[1024];
            if (UnDecorateSymbolName(pSymbolInfo->Name, undName,
                sizeof(undName),
                UNDNAME_NO_MS_KEYWORDS |
                UNDNAME_NO_ACCESS_SPECIFIERS |
                UNDNAME_NO_FUNCTION_RETURNS |
                UNDNAME_NO_ALLOCATION_MODEL |
                UNDNAME_NO_ALLOCATION_LANGUAGE |
                UNDNAME_NO_ARGUMENTS |
                UNDNAME_NO_SPECIAL_SYMS |
                UNDNAME_NO_MEMBER_TYPE))
            {
                //Ignore the unnecessary calls emulated from std library
                if (strstr(undName, "std::"))
                {
                    //Skip the symbol
                }
                else
                {
                    strcpy_s(undName, pSymbolInfo->Name);
                    szFuncName = new char[strlen(undName) + 2];
                    strcpy_s(szFuncName, strlen(undName) + 1, undName);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
            FormatMessage(
                FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
                FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
                FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                NULL,
                lastError,
                MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
                (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf,
                0, NULL);
            lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT,
                (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR));

            StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf,
                LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
                TEXT("failed with error %d: %s"),
                lastError, lpMsgBuf);
        }
    }
}

//define static methods outside of class
SymbolResolverSingleton* SymbolResolverSingleton::pinstance_{ nullptr };
std::mutex SymbolResolverSingleton::mutex_;

SymbolResolverSingleton* SymbolResolverSingleton::GetInstance(void* pAddress)
{
    if (pinstance_ == nullptr)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        if (pinstance_ == nullptr)
        {
            pinstance_ = new SymbolResolverSingleton(pAddress);
        }
    }
    return pinstance_;
}

and its header:
#pragma once
#include <mutex>

class SymbolResolverSingleton
{
    static SymbolResolverSingleton* pinstance_;
    static std::mutex mutex_;

    void InitSymbols(const void* pAddress);

protected:
    SymbolResolverSingleton(const void* pAddress);
    ~SymbolResolverSingleton();

public:
    // prevent cloning
    SymbolResolverSingleton(SymbolResolverSingleton& other) = delete;

    //prevent assigning
    void operator= (const SymbolResolverSingleton&) = delete;

    static SymbolResolverSingleton* GetInstance(void* pAddress);

    void FindFunction(DWORD64 pa, char*& szFuncName);
};

Maybe this is also caused by the assembler code but I am not very familiar with coding in assembler and basically just took the code from the tutorial.
extern TimeStart:PROC ; from dll
extern TimeStop:PROC ; from dll

.code
PUSHREGS    macro
    push    rax
    push    rcx
    push    rdx
    push    r8
    push    r9
    push    r10
    push    r11

endm

POPREGS     macro
    pop     r11
    pop     r10
    pop     r9
    pop     r8
    pop     rdx
    pop     rcx
    pop     rax
endm

_penter PROC
    ; Save non-volatile registers
    PUSHREGS
    sub rsp, 32  ; Allocate space for args that do not fit in registers if needed

    ; Get the return address of the function
    mov rcx,rsp
    mov rcx,qword ptr[rcx+88] ; go up 88 bytes (7 registers * 8 bytes + 32 bytes)
    sub rcx,5
    call TimeStart

    ; Restore non-volatile registers
    add rsp, 32  ; Adjust stack pointer to deallocate space for xmm registers if needed
    POPREGS

    ret
_penter ENDP


_pexit PROC
    ; Save non-volatile registers
    PUSHREGS
    sub rsp, 32  ; Allocate space for xmm registers if needed

    ; Get the return address of the function
    mov rcx,rsp
    mov rcx,qword ptr[rcx+88] ; go up 88 bytes (7 registers * 8 bytes + 32 bytes)
    call TimeStop

    ; Restore non-volatile registers
    add rsp, 32  ; Adjust stack pointer to deallocate space for xmm registers if needed
    POPREGS

    ret
_pexit ENDP

END


What is a debugger?

@Eljay I know it seems like an easy to solve problem with the debugger. However, debugging did not help in this case. The code works for the small project but not for the other one which seems to be a deeper problem

you need to debug the other one.

The other application works fine if I do not compile it with the /GH /Gh compiler options. It only throws the exception if I do add them and fails at the first function it jumps into. I am debugging both at the same time if this is what you meant. So the debugger + application are debugged in the same session in Visual Studio.

There is nothing thread safe about that class beyond the instance creation.

@molbdnilo what exactly does it not make thread safe? The thread that wants to access an object needs to create a mutex on it. If there already is a mutex it needs to wait. The function is only called with the GetInstance() call. SymbolResolverSingleton::GetInstance(nullptr)->FindFunction(pCallee, szCallee);

@foskimova That expression is not executed atomically; the GetInstance call is "safe" but FindFunction isn't (it's exactly like if you saved the pointer in a variable first). You need to synchronize around the unsafe functions.

Have you tried asking Babu Abdulsalam?  I suspect that the assumptions in Babu's 10-year-old project are either not entirely correct, and/or have not aged well with the current compiler.

@molbdnilo I see. I added a lock at the beginning of the function that is removed when it goes out of scope just like with the object above. However this still leads to the same exception as before. Do you have another idea what could be the issue?

@foskimova Also note that your instance is only initialized once, so only the pAddress for the very 1st call of getInstance() will be used, values passed into subsequent calls of getInstance() will be ignored. It really doesn't make sense to pass any memory address into getInstance() at all.

@Remy Lebeau thanks for pointing this out. I know this is a bit ugly but the behaviour is expected as I only want to use it for a single application

The dbghelp functions are not thread safe.

Note that all DbgHelp functions are single threaded. Therefore, calls
from more than one thread to this function will likely result in
unexpected behavior or memory corruption. To avoid this, you must
synchronize all concurrent calls from more than one thread to this
function.

So calls to your method SymbolResolverSingleton::FindFunction from multiple threads are not thread safe.
Your mutex only makes the singleton thread-safe.
As of C++11 you can make the singleton thread-safe with following pattern:
SymbolResolverSingleton* SymbolResolverSingleton::GetInstance(void* pAddress)
{
    static SymbolResolverSingleton instance{pAddress};
    return &instance;
}

The easiest way to make it thread safe is to use the mutex for the whole method.
#pragma once
#include <mutex>

class SymbolResolverSingleton
{
    std::mutex mutex_;
    ...

void SymbolResolverSingleton::FindFunction(DWORD64 pa, char*& szFuncName)
{
   std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
   ...
}


Thank you for your answer, however, the Singleton you suggest (first code block) for GetInstance creates a new instance each time it is called. Also, &instance  returns an object of type SymbolResolverSingleton** which is incompatible with the return type. The mutex I implemented but does not seem to fix the problem. It might not be the SymFromAddr to cause this after all but only a symptom of the real problem.

@foskimova No, the variable is static, so it lives "forever" and is only initialized on the first call (it is also guaranteed to be thread-safe). And instance is a SymbolResolverSingleton, so &instance is a SymbolResolverSingleton*.

All of the dbghlp functions are not thread safe.  If it's still crashing then more likely that you are calling dbghlp functions somewhere in your code else that is NOT under that single mutex instance.  Any overlapping calls in ANY dbghlp function calls can cause this problem.

These issues, particularly in a larger project where memory management and symbol resolution become more complex, could easily lead to the access violation error you’re encountering. Ensuring proper error handling, validating memory access, and ensuring that the stack and symbols are correctly managed can help solve your issue.
I was able to look into the code sample you provided and made these observations.

Potential Invalid Module Base Address Handling:
VirtualQuery((void*)pAddress, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)); GetModuleFileNameA((HMODULE)mbi.AllocationBase, moduleName, MAX_PATH);
Here, the code assumes that VirtualQuery will always return a valid AllocationBase in mbi. However, if pAddress is not part of a valid memory region in a larger project, mbi.AllocationBase could be invalid, resulting in GetModuleFileNameA receiving a null or incorrect module handle. This can lead to an incorrect or uninitialized moduleName, which in turn causes issues when initializing symbols.

Lack of Error Handling for SymInitialize and SymLoadModule64:
bInitResult = SymInitialize(GetCurrentProcess(), moduleName, TRUE); dwBaseAddr = SymLoadModule64(GetCurrentProcess(), NULL, (PCSTR)moduleName, NULL, (DWORD)mbi.AllocationBase, 0);
This part of the code does not verify if SymInitialize or SymLoadModule64 actually succeed. In a larger project, where the module size and complexity increase, these functions are more prone to failure, especially if the symbol paths are not correctly set or if the module is not properly loaded. Failing to check the return values can lead to subsequent calls like SymFromAddr operating on an invalid symbol context, leading to access violations.

Incorrect Stack Manipulation in Assembly Code:
Even though am not very good at Assembly programming, This code sample,
mov rcx,qword ptr[rcx+88] ; go up 88 bytes (7 registers * 8 bytes + 32 bytes) sub rcx,5 call TimeStart
assumes that the stack frame is always structured in a specific way, which may not hold true in a larger project with more complex calling conventions or optimizations. If rcx does not correctly point to the return address, attempting to access qword ptr[rcx+88] could result in reading an invalid memory location, which may explain the access violation.

Improper Handling of Decorated vs. Undecorated Symbol Names:
if (UnDecorateSymbolName(pSymbolInfo->Name, undName, sizeof(undName), ...) == 0) { strcpy_s(undName, pSymbolInfo->Name); }
This section of the code tries to undecorate symbol names but does not adequately handle the case where UnDecorateSymbolName fails (returns 0). In such a case, the fallback mechanism copies the potentially decorated symbol name back to undName, which could cause issues if UnDecorateSymbolName returns an error or the decorated name is not properly managed.


My point is that you should introduce validation checks in some parts of the code since the big project might have undefined behavior on the configuration that works for the small project.
Happy coding!
